# Issue in changing the color of a word in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, text, colors

I created a layout for an `AlertDialog` in which there's a `TextView` that shows some text. For the text I have an item in `strings.xml` where I would like to change the color of a single word, just like in the image below.
I tried with this:

```
<string name="dialog_text">Text... <font fgcolor="#000000">TheWordIWantInBlack</font> text text text.</string>
```

The issue is when I run this on the device (Galaxy Note3) that shows all the text in the dialog except for the word in the `<font>` tag but on the emulator (Nexus 5 with Android 6.0) everything is ok, exactly how I want it.
Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fgcolor` replace `#000000` with `black`, like

```
<string name="dialog_text">Text... <font fgcolor="black">TheWordIWantInBlack</font> text text text.</string>
```

**This only works on a relatively short list of built-in colors: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, green, grey, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow**

Answer (score 0):

Use Spannable String, for example

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Allow ");
SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString("WhatsApp");
s1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, s1.length(), 0);
sb.append(s1);
```

and sb is now "Allow **WhatsApp**"

In this example, I use type Bold for the styled string, but of course you can customize it by setting font colors and other attributes to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but I need the text in strings.xml

Comment: why? you can also have your text in string and use Spannable String to format the style of the subtext.

Comment: I have to translate the text for many countries when I'll publish the app on Google Play, so I need the text in a single string. I'd like to understand why my solution works in the emulator but not on the device